# How to showstrings in Listview in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to show some contacts information those are stored in a file in the list view.I want each contact to be shown in a separate cell rather than all together in a same place.Now all the contacts are showing in a single cell in the list view.I used a special character to check the end of a contact information.
Thanks in advance :)

Here is my code:

```
public void show_contacts()
 {

     final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
     final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
     String data_read="";
     String FILENAME = "myfile.txt";
     StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        String s1="";
        try {

            fis = openFileInput("myfile.txt");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

            while (fis.read(buffer) != -1) {


                if(s1.endsWith("."))
                {
                    data_read=fileContent.toString();
                    list.add(data_read);
                }
                else
                  s1+=buffer.toString();
                 fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          data_read=fileContent.toString();
          list.add(data_read); 
     listview.setAdapter(adapter);
 }



   public void Write_to_file(String cName2,String cNumber2)
   {
      String string=cName2+"--"+cNumber2;
      String FILENAME="myfile.txt";
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      Context c=this.getBaseContext();

        try {
                String s=".";
                fos = c.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                fos.write(string.getBytes());
                fos.write(s.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

My wish is you don't write the contact name into text file you Just write your Contacts in the custom Class like

```
public class Sample {
private String listitem1;
private String listitem2;

public String getListitem1() {
    return listitem1;
}
public void setListitem1(String listitem1) {
    this.listitem1 = listitem1;
}
public String getListitem2() {
    return listitem2;
}
public void setListitem2(String listitem2) {
    this.listitem2 = listitem2;
}
}
```

**And use  this custom adapter in your program...**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());      
    return convertView;
}

    }
```

**And use this code into your Activity....**

```
    private ArrayList<Sample> mListItems;
private PullToRefreshListView mPullRefreshListView;
private CustomAdapter mAdapter;

private String[] mStrings = { "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
        "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
        "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
        "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
        "Allgauer Emmentaler" };    

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ptr_list);
    mListItems= new ArrayList<Sample>();

    mPullRefreshListView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_list);
    Calculation();

    mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void Calculation() {
    for(int i=0;i<mStrings.length;i++)
    {
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.setListitem1(mStrings[i]);
        sample.setListitem2(mStrings[i]);
        mListItems.add(sample);
    }


}
```

**And you just replace with you Contact Name and Number in the Above sample..**